# Largest entry in symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know why in a symmetric positive definite matrix every entry on the trace is positive entry $a_{ii}>0$. However I don't how to show that the largest value of the matrix is also on it's trace, meaning a $z$ exist with $a_{zz} = max \vert a_{ij} \vert $ for  $1\le i,j\le n$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: when $i \neq j,$ what do you know about $a_{ii} a_{jj} - a_{ij}^2? $

Comment: Hello, well it has to be positive because every minor of the matrix must have a positive determinant.

Comment: and what about the larger of $a_{ii}, a_{jj}?$

Comment: One of $a_{ii}$,$a_{ji}$ must be the largest because it's a symmetric matrix and therefore for every 2x2 minor I have $a_{ii}*a_{jj}$ minus a square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, every diagonal element of $A$ is positive since 
$$
0<e_i^\top A e_i=a_{ii}
$$

Let $a_{kk}$ be the largest diagonal element of $A$ and let $i\neq j$. Since $A$ is positive-definite, every principal submatrix of $A$ is positive-definite. In particular, 
$$
0<\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{ii} & a_{ij} \\
a_{ji} & a_{jj}
\end{bmatrix}
=a_{ii}a_{jj}-a_{ji}a_{ij}=a_{ii}a_{jj}-a_{ij}^2<a_{kk}^2-a_{ij}^2
$$
What can we conclude?

Comment: I don't understand why this determinant must be positive. The criterion (at least the one I know) says that the determinant of every $k \times k$ submatrix in the upper left corner of $A$ must be positive, but the matrix you consider is not a $2\times 2$ submatrix (unless $i=1$ and $j=2$).

Comment: @user500094 If every leading principal minor is positive, then every principal minor is positive.